# Partitioning kernel modules

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am working on a project which consists of multiple kernel modules. There is some shared functionality between the different modules, but I don't want to include the same code in each module. Does the Linux kernel have a "shared object library" or does the common code go into a separate module?

Comment: @amrzar 25% was what he was suggesting that you better. StackOverflow is good not because it is filled with questions people have asked to learn but because a lot of people spend time writing good answers to them. If you get a good answer you should mark it as such or people will not think it is worth the effort to answer and help you learn. Saying things like "Pull your ass" when you get a good advice is probably not a very clever way to get more help.

Comment: @Fredrik I think, i have different understanding from word "Accept", people always ask someone opinions and should respect others but respecting others opinion _DOES NOT_ mean you should "Accept" it! If we accept every people opinion just to "Respect", There would be no sectarian violence, political parties and stuff these hands! Respect to others people work is shown by literary thanking them by writing sweet comments and wishing them success!

Comment: @Fredrik seems you are right and its type of rule and regulation for this forum! I'll do so now on, thanks for ur time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, you would put the functionality common to the modules in a separate module itself. A good example of this is the `drivers/scsi/libsas` module used by other SAS (Serial Attached SCSI) device drivers. If you go this route, see the kernel documentation in section 6.3 of `Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt` for suggestions on referencing symbols from other external modules.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a way to share functions between modules you should take a look at `EXPORT_SYMBOL` macro. A simple example:

file super.c

```
void call_me(){
   printk("Hello from super.\n");
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(call_me);
```

file super.h

```
extern void call_me();
```

file base.c

```
#include "super.h"

void call_super(){
   call_me();
}
```

Here super.c and base.c are different modules.

If this is what you're looking for let me know. I can send you a more complex example with makefiles and stuff. Hope it helps.

Note: I've used this in many distros... however each time I did it I needed to copy the file Modules.symvers to each other module directory.

Supose you have a module A and a module B, which uses functions from A. Upon compiling A, a file named Modules.symvers is created. I've needed to copy that file to B's folder before compiling it. Just don't issue `make clean` in B's folder after copying Modules.symvers, or it will get deleted.